# edit javafx tableview populated with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tableview

I created a tableview in my app which displays value from derbydb using Hibernate. It works ok, now I would like to make the table editable, but I do not understand how to proceed; I tried adding setOnEditCommit.... but it does not work, how can I proceed ?

```
@FXML protected void cercaProd(ActionEvent event) {
    magaz_table.getItems().clear();
    magaz_table.setEditable(true);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String cercanome=txtfield_cerca_prod.getText();
    String sQuery = "from Magazzino WHERE ITEM_NOME=:nomeprod";
    Query q3 = session.createQuery(sQuery);
    q3.setParameter("nomeprod", txtfield_cerca_prod.getText());
        List result = q3.list();
        Iterator iterator = result.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              Magazzino obj = (Magazzino)iterator.next();
              data.add(obj);
        }
    itemIdCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Magazzino, Integer>("itemId"));             
    NomeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Magazzino, String>("itemNome"));
    NomeCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    NomeCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Magazzino, String> t) -> {
            ((Magazzino) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setItemNome(t.getNewValue());        
    });
    magaz_table.setItems(data);    
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Part of fxml

```
<TableView fx:id="magaz_table" editable="true" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="407.0" prefWidth="800.0">
      <columns>
           <TableColumn fx:id="itemIdCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="Id" />
           <TableColumn fx:id="NomeCol" editable="true" prefWidth="75.0" text="Nome" />
      </columns>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Did you set a `cellFactory` (as well as a `cellValueFactory`) on `NomeCol`?

Comment: I modified the code with the setting for cellFactory, but still nothing;

Comment: Very happy to tell you that with one of your previous answer I solved my issue; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465181/tableview-update-database-on-edit