# how to edit in tableview and save it in database

Tags: java, mysql, class, javafx, tableview

i have a tableview with column

```
private TableView<User> dgv_user;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User,String> id;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> nom;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> prenom;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> cin;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> dn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> tel;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User,String> adresse;
```

and class User

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private  String nom;
    private  String prenom;
    private  String cin;
    private  String tel;
    private  String adresse;
    private  String dn;
```

so i want to edit tableview and this data send to database when i click the button

Comment: There are many examples of this on this site. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465181/tableview-update-database-on-edit

Comment: yes, thanks but i did not understand this exemple

Comment: What did you not understand?  Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: the function updataData() and setOnEditComit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    >        nom.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User>forTableColumn());
    >        prenom.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User>forTableColumn());
    >        cin.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User>forTableColumn());
    >        dn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User>forTableColumn());
    >        adresse.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User>forTableColumn());
    >        tel.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User>forTableColumn());
    >     }
```

and in tablecolumn sitoneditcomit

```
@FXML
    void edit_colnom(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) throws SQLException {
        User u= event.getRowValue();
        u.modifier_user("nom",event.getNewValue(), u.getId());      
    }

    @FXML
    void edit_colprenom(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) throws SQLException {
        User u= event.getRowValue();
        u.modifier_user("prenom",event.getNewValue(), u.getId());  
    }

    @FXML
    void edit_coltele(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) throws SQLException {
        User u= event.getRowValue();
        u.modifier_user("tele",event.getNewValue(), u.getId());  
    }


    @FXML
    void edit_coladresse(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) throws SQLException {
        User u= event.getRowValue();
        u.modifier_user("adresse",event.getNewValue(), u.getId());  
    }

    @FXML
    void edit_colcin(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) throws SQLException {
        User u= event.getRowValue();
        u.modifier_user("cin",event.getNewValue(), u.getId());  
    }

    @FXML
    void edit_coldn(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) throws SQLException {
        User u= event.getRowValue();
        u.modifier_user("dn",event.getNewValue(), u.getId());  
    }
```