# Updating DB Table after editing jafavFx table

Tags: java, sql, javafx

Right now I am trying to implement an editable Tableview with javafx and I have one problem. So far I can double click on a cell and write a new Value inside it. But the problem is I can not update the database

The use case is that I can add routes in a form and I have to be able to edit these routes so while adding

So far is here what I tried:

Code to Edit table

```
 public void editTable() throws SQLException {

// This is in order to fill the box with the db values. But it is empty

            ObservableList<String> planes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ObservableList<String> startFlughafen = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ObservableList<String> zielFlughafen = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


            Statement stateMentAirplane = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet myRsAirplane = stateMentAirplane.executeQuery(
                    "select * from gesellschaftflugzeuge where fluggesellschaft =\"" + fluggesellschaft + "\"");
            while (myRsAirplane.next()) {
                planes.add(myRsAirplane.getString("Hersteller"));

            }

            startAirport.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn());
            airplane.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn());



        }




        public void prepareUpdateTable( String startFlughafen
                ) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement pStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("Update fluglinie set startFlughafen =? ");

            pStatement.setString(1, startFlughafen
                    );




        }

        public void initiateUpdateTable() {
            try {
                prepareUpdateTable(startAirport.getCellFactory().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

initialize Table

```
public void initializeTable() {

        try {

            // Ablesen
            Statement pStatement = connection.createStatement();
            flightList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet myRs = pStatement
                    .executeQuery("select * from fluglinie where fluggesellschaft =\"" + fluggesellschaft + "\"");
            while (myRs.next()) {
                flightList.add(new flightRouteAddModel(myRs.getString("startFlughafen"),
                        myRs.getString("zielFlughafen"), myRs.getString("startDatum"), myRs.getString("flugzeug"),
                        myRs.getInt("intervall"), 

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }

        startAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startAirport"));
        targetAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("targetAirport"));
        flightDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightDate"));
        airplane.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("airPlane"));
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setItems(flightList);
        initiateUpdateTable();

        try {
            editTable();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I thank you for all answers before hand

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the _M_ (no need for dozens of properties, one is enough) and don't forget: it's _not_ your production code we want to see, but an example written for the sole purpose of demonstrating what you are after and why/how it doesn't behave as expected. Also note: one-problem-per-question :)

Comment: Oh ok sorry I will keep that in mind for next time should I edit my question or is it ok if its stays like this just this once ?

Comment: please edit your question :)

Comment: I edited now I hope this is fine now :) the code now Only have things which is relevant for the question

Comment: right direction :) But still not a [mcve] - please read the help page and act accordingly. The idea is that somebody can throw the example _without change_ into their favorite IDE and see what happens.

Comment: @user11343077 Have a look at this question or consider another controller class to do the update (edit) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465181/tableview-update-database-on-edit